# The Dirac equation for helium?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

How to write down the Dirac equation for the two electrons in the helium atom? The problem is the interaction term, as $1/|r_1 - r_2|$ is apparently not Lorent-covariant.

Comment: Here is a paper that answers your question. http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7567

Comment: @illia Unpublished?

Comment: Here is a published one: http://www.sciencedomain.org/abstract/13496